Identify this scifi tv episode from a story per week style show ~2000's?
I think this was a show that had a different story each episode. 
The episode I am thinking of was about the crew of a spaceship that get an emergency that (for reasons I can't remember, computer malfunction?) if there is more than one living person on board, they will all die. Of course they all go a bit psycho and end up killing each other until only one is left.
The twist at the end is that is was all just a drill. So it's presented kinda like a dark comedy...
Would have been roughly early 2000's when I saw it.

Hi and welcome to M&TV. Please read the Identify-This-X section on this page; your question is currently lacking some basic details. If you remember or can approximate any of them, please edit them in.

The 100 (TV series) ; Season 1:Ep 3 : Earth Kills ??
The Culling; incase you want to search more and see if this is what you are referring to??
pics 1: is the banner, 2: is the culling image,  3 & 4 my girlfriend in the cast. she says hi




i am just having fun. not my girlfriend but is this what you are talking about.

No, sorry not this. Regards to your girlfriend though! Its older, early 2000's i think. and as mentioned in the question, its like a new story each episode kinda like twilight zone-ish.
